# How do I properly set up my Keystone.js app to run in docker with mongo?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, keystonejs

I have built my app which runs fine locally. When I try to run it in docker (**docker-compose up**) it appears to start, but then throws an error message:

```
Creating mongodb ... done
Creating webcms  ... done
Attaching to mongodb, webcms

...

Mongoose connection "error" event fired with:
    MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect

...

webcms exited with code 1
```

I have read that with **Keystone.js** you need to configure the Mongo location in the **.env** file, which I have:

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017
```

Here is my Docker file:

```
# Use node 9.4.0
FROM node:9.4.0

# Copy source code
COPY . /app

# Change working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Expose API port to the outside
EXPOSE 3000

# Launch application
CMD ["node","keystone"]
```

...and my docker-compose

```
version: "2"
services:
  # NodeJS app
  web:
    container_name: webcms
    build: .
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
    - mongo

  # MongoDB
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db/mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

When I run **docker ps** it confirms that mongo is up and running in a container...

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
f3e06e4a5cfe        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb
```

I am either missing some config or I have it configured incorrectly. Could someone tell me what that is?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not working properly because you are sending the wrong host.
your container does not understand what is `localhost:27017` since it's your computer address and not its container address.

Important to understand that each service has it's own container with a different IP.
The beauty of the docker-compose that you do not need to know your container address! enough to know your service name:

```
version: "2"

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - "db-data:/data/db/mongo"
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

just run `docker-compose up` and you are all-set

Comment: Using this way will create data inside the project files. How to store mongodb DB into ubuntu external folder. To be safe from deletion.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that may help:

First. I am not sure what your error logs look like but buried in my error logs was:

`...Error: The cookieSecret config option is required when running Keystone in a production environment.Update your app or environment config so this value is supplied to the Keystone constructor....`

To solve this problem, in your Keystone entry file (eg: index.js) make sure your Keystone constructor has the `cookieSecret` parameter set correctly: `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`

Next. Change the mongo uri from the one Keystone generated (`mongoUri: mongodb://localhost/my-keystone`) to: `mongoUri: 'mongodb://mongo:27017'`. Docker needs this because it is the mongo container address. This change should also be reflected in your docker-compose file under the environment variable under MONGO_URI:

`... environment: - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017 ...`

After these changes your Keystone constructor should look like this:

```
const keystone = new Keystone({
  adapter: new Adapter(adapterConfig),
  cookieSecret: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  sessionStore: new MongoStore({ url: 'mongodb://mongo:27017' }),
});
```

And your docker-compose file, something like this (I used a network instead of links for my docker-compose as Docker has stated that [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links) are a legacy option. I've included mine in case its useful for anyone else):

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mongo:
      image: mongo
      networks:
       - appNetwork
      ports:
       - "27017:27017"
      environment:
       - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017
  appservice:
      build:
        context: ./my-app
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      networks:
        - appNetwork
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
networks:
 appNetwork:
   external: false
```

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use mongo db atlas if you does not want complications. You can use it in local and in deployment.

Simple steps to get the mongo url is available in https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas

Then add a env variable 
CONNECT_TO=mongodb://your_url

For passing the .env to docker, use

```
docker run --publish 8000:3000 --env-file .env --detach --name kb keystoneblog:1.0
```